# NextAuth + TwitterProvider + FirestoreAdapter => Missing Screen Name

Tags: twitter-oauth, next-auth

I'm using `next-auth` along with `next-auth/firebase-adapter` packages to log to my web app via Twitter. The flow is working nicely, but I can not obtain the user's screenname (aka handle).

Before using `next-auth` I've been using Firebase auth(). In their package, the user's screen name has always been available.

I've been playing around with `NextAuthOptions` but to no avail.
Does anyone know how to make add the user's screenname to the session?

```js
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firebaseConfig),
    pages: {
        signIn: '/sign-in',
    },
    callbacks: {
        session: ({ session, token }) => {
            return {
                ...session,
                user: {
                    ...session.user,
                    id: token.sub!,
                },
            }
        },
    },
    events: {
        createUser: async ({ user }) => {
            const ref = admin
                .firestore()
                .collection(Constants.UsersTable)
                .doc(user.id)

            await ref.set(
                {
                    screenName: <MISSING>,
                    daily_target: 0,
                    onboarded: false,
                },
                { merge: true }
            )
        },
    },
    providers: [
        TwitterProvider({
            clientId: process.env.TWITTER_AUTH_CLIENTID,
            clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_AUTH_CLIENTSECRET,
            version: '2.0',
        }),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of obtaining the `screenname` I decided to obtain the `providerAccountToken` and add it to my JWT token with a `next-auth` callback.

This is even better as I use the unique user id instead of a public handle (which the user might change in the future).

```js
    callbacks: {
        jwt: ({ token, account = {} }) => {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (account.providerAccountId) {
                token.providerAccountId = account.providerAccountId
            }

            return token
        },
    },
```